# FreeBSD open syscall returning 2 instead of -1 on error

Tags: c, system-calls, freebsd

I am writing a program in C for FreeBSD where the whole idea is that I don't use Libc or any libraries at all. For now, I have manually written some small wrappers for syscalls in order to use them in my code.

For some reason, my sys_open wrapper is returning 2 instead of -1 when I attempt to open a file that does not exist.

```
.global sys_open
sys_open:
    mov $5, %eax
    int $0x80
    ret
```

```c
        fd = sys_open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);

        /* weird bug where passing a non-existing file to sys_open returns 2 instead of -1.
         * here is a temporary fix, since 0, 1, and 2 will always be taken anyway. */
        if (fd < 3) {
            const char* errmessage = "error: failed to open file\n";
            sys_write(STDERR_FILENO, errmessage, strlen(errmessage));
            return errno;
        }
```

Yes, I am using a 32-bit FreeBSD system, don't ask why.

Here is a link to the whole project. The relevant files should be lib/syscalls/syscalls_i386.s and src/cat.c
https://github.com/minneelyyyy/uutils

This question really is just a shot in the dark, since I have no clue what could possibly be going on. My syscall wrappers work otherwise, including the open one. I've single stepped it in the debugger, checking to make sure that it is actually passing what I expect it to be passing (it is), and checking the return value, which is always 2 when the file does not exist.

Comment: What is the numeric value of ENOENT on this system?
If you disassemble the syscall stub for open() in FreeBSD libc, how does it detect errors?

Comment: Pretty sure that at one level, syscalls return 0 for success, and an errno value on failure.  (And 2 is `ENOENT` is "No such file or directory".)

Comment: Isn't negative numbers for errors a Linux thing? Doesn't FreeBSD use the carry flag or something to indicate errors instead?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thank you! It looks like the systemcall wrappers in found in the various system libraries differ from the actual system calls themselves. I rewrote my wrappers to check the carry flag and if so, return -1 and set errno.